# EditText restricting Copy/Paste when view is being added to WindowManager

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, copy-paste, android-windowmanager

I am adding a textview to Window using the following code

```
public static void addViewToWindow(Activity activity, View view, WindowManager.LayoutParams params)
{
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.addView(view, params);
}

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
params.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE;

addViewToWindow(myActivity, myEditText, params);
```

But I am not able to long press on the EditText to let the user copy/paste. As soon as I change the orientation of the device to landscape, the EditText covers the entire screen and I am able to copy/paste by long press. I am not able to make out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;` ?

Comment: sorry @H.Brooks. how does that help?

Comment: Hi @VarunBhatia ! Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @IvanSadovyi Thanks for checking but I dont recall getting its solution